# How do I get an animation's effect to persist between activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I've been successfully using animation in my project, with TranslateAnimation objects, but when I return to the activity whose views have been animated, they redraw at their default positions.

So, for example,

1. I create an activity called HomeActivity. The content draws as defined in the XML. A View (myTextView) might appear at position0.
2. I can use a TranslateAnimation to move myTextView to position1.
3. I can click a button (or whatever) to start, say, MenuActivity.
4. I exit MenuActivity and resume HomeActivity.

**(What I'm seeing)**
myTextView shows up at position0 again.

**(What I'd like to see)**
myTextView is drawn at position1.

Here's how I perform the animation.

```
TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

private void animate()
{
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, displacementX, 0, displacementY);
anim.setDuration(200);
anim.setAnimationListener(this); // This activity implements AnimationListener
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
myTextview.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd( Animation animation )
{
 myTextview.clearAnimation();
}
```

Are there any flags I should set, maybe in the above procedure, onPause or in onAnimationEnd, that would cause the Views to retain their post-animated state? Or do I need to save their locations before starting the new activity and shift them in onResume? Or is there another way altogether?


Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Forgot to specify, minimum SDK is 2.2 (API 8).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove myTextview.clearAnimation(); from above code and see. And comment me for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `TranslateAnimation` for this, try using `ObjectAnimator` as it actually move the views. When using `TranslateAnimation` the views never change place, it only seems so. If this is not enough, try saving the view's location in `onSaveInstanceState` and in `onRestoreInstanceState` you can position the view to this locations.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the rapid answer! I'll try both suggestions and give you a shiny, green tick if one of them works :D

Comment: Whoops, forgot to specify that my minimum SDK is 2.2, so the ObjectAnimator is a no go(?).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems onRestoreInstanceState is only called when the Activity has been killed and not necessarily onResume, so it doesn't apply to what I need. +1 for the useful information about TranslateAnimation.

Comment: Back again, I used the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) package to give me access to ObjectAnimator and it did the trick!